# Creating a new data frame by filtering an old one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have imported a large .csv file. I want to create new df's that filter by one of the names in one of the columns.
Something like this:

```
Field     Formation    Depth

 Oseberg  Brage    1225 

Troll   stockberg 1500 
   
Tune     Bragg    1305 

Oseberg  Stockberg 1600
```

I want to make a new df for the Field Oseberg :

```
Field  Formation  Depth

Oseberg  Brage    1225

Oseberg  Stockberg 1600
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide sample input so we can play around with the code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ```new_df = df.loc[df['Field'] == 'Oseberg']``` ?

Comment: post as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dataframe based on the string in a column

```
import pandas as pd 
    
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv") 

df_new = df.loc[(df['Field'].str.contains('Oseberg')]
```

or

```
import pandas as pd 
    
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv") 

df_new = df.loc[df['Field'] == 'Oseberg']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do filtering with the required column, like this

```
df[df.'Field'] == 'Oseberg']
```